# expected string or bytes-like object- Amazon dataset

Tags: python

I was working on an Amazon data set to perform LSTM. The code as below:

```
def data_clean( rev, remove_stopwords=True): 


new_text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]"," ", rev)

words = new_text.lower().split()

if remove_stopwords:
    sts = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    words = [w for w in words if not w in sts]
    return words
ary=[]
eng_stemmer = english_stemmer 
for word in words:
    ary.append(eng_stemmer.stem(word))


return ary
```

But as soon as I run clean _reviewData and clean_summarydata it returns an error as below.
[image]

Can someone help me to correct the code?

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: which like makes problem - show full error message. If you know which line makes problem then first check what you have in variables in this line - you can use `print(...)` for this - and also `print(type( ... ))` and `print(len(...))` if it is list.

Comment: I think all problem can be missing `return words` in `data_clean` - i fyou don't use `return words` then it runs `returns None` - so in place of `" ".join(data_clean(rev))` you get `" ".join(None)` and this can gives you error.

Comment: I am so sorry for my mistakes in formulating correctly the question, is the 1st time I use stack overflow :(. I modified the code as you suggested, but still the error. I modified the original question in a muck detailed one. Hope is a little bit clearer than before. Thanks for the help!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You did't format code correctly but I expect you have function

```
def data_clean( rev, remove_stopwords=True): 
    new_text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]"," ", rev)
    words = new_text.lower().split()
    if remove_stopwords:
        sts = set(stopwords.words("english"))
        words = [w for w in words if not w in sts]
```

and you forgot `return words` at the end - so it runs `return None` and later `" ".join(data_clean(rev))` gives you `" ".join(None)` and this  gives error `expected string or bytes-like object`. Because `None` is not `string or bytes-like object`.

You need

```
def data_clean( rev, remove_stopwords=True): 
    new_text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]"," ", rev)
    words = new_text.lower().split()

    if remove_stopwords:
        sts = set(stopwords.words("english"))
        words = [w for w in words if not w in sts]

    return words
```

Comment: I am so sorry for my mistakes in formulating correctly the question, is the 1st time I use stack overflow :(. I modified the code as you suggested, but still the error. I modified the original question in a muck detailed one. Hope is a little bit clearer than before.  Thanks for the help!! :)